# Launcher close Handler Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem when I try to run my app in my phone.

- I have installed Go Launcher, launcher closes the handler .
- If i uninstall the launcher the problem solved.

How can I avoid this kind of problem? Because lots of users have different launchers.

**This is my handler:**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

...

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(isConnectingToInternet(getApplicationContext())){
            new thread().execute();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
    }
};
```

Of course the problem is when i screen off my phone. In others phones like Moto X, moto G, etc works properly

Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: maybe the launcher is doing some taskManager like stuff after screen off. ..look into the launcher settings if there is anything like energy saving or something else that hints to closing apps/saving resources.....

Comment: Are you sure this is because of the launcher? Because i doubt any app can close handler of other app. I if your handler is in activity it will be killed if the activity is closes.

Comment: Some device have problem and my app crashed. But  that devices have launcher or energy saving. How can i handle something like this? Other devices have not problem with the app